# What does giving someone a lollipop mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, idioms

A quote by Alan Perlis says,

> When someone says "I want a programming language in which I need only say what I wish done," give him a lollipop.

Such a programming language doesn't exist and Perlis is being critical of the ignorance of the person. But what does "give him a lollipop" mean exactly? Can you give a few more example sentences where this idiom is used?

Comment: It is not a widely-used expression - but I think we can all deduce that it means the request is so childishly unreasonable that "give him/her a lollipop" is justifiable as a patronising response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this site](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Give%20Him%20a%20Lollipop), when you give someone a lollipop,  you are treating him as a "nice but useless person who you don’t want to involve but also you don’t want to be excluded".

> Give him a lollipop and let him sit & listen to the discussion.

There is a tone of condescension in this phrase, and in your example Perlis is clearly critical of the ignorance of the person.